# Need help to understand EXISTS behaviour/return

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

I am a beginner. As I understand, EXISTS will return true if the subquery contains any rows. Does that mean there's only one boolean returned?

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T1.ID= T2.ID
);
```

For example: this query should return tuples of Table 1 only where the IDs from both table match. But if EXISTS returns only 1 true (because the subquery is not empty - there's at least one row) then shouldn't it be equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE TRUE;
```

Shouldn't it return all the rows in Table 1? If EXISTS **returns a boolean every time a row is not empty** then it would make much more sense to me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be misinterpreting the logic of your first query.  In plain English, your exists query says to return every record from `TABLE1` for which we can find a record in `TABLE2` having the same `ID`.  Note that the query inside the exists clause is logically evaluated for *every* record in `TABLE1`.  It does not just execute once.